# How to have a store using dialog in ROBLOX

Tags: roblox

Using the new "Dialog" feature I want to create a store, how would I do that, like they click on an option and the game gives them the weapon they want.

Yeah so this feature is fairly new, but this is also my first store.

Answer (score 2):

The tree should be like this

- Dialog

  - DialogChoice

    - UserResponse: What the text shows for the user

      - ResponseDialog: What the dialog's text becomes when the user clicks the choice

To detect when a user clicks it...

```
Dialog.DialogChoiceSelected:connect(function(player, dialogChoice)
    -- Do stuff
end)
```

'player' is an actual Player, and 'dialogChoice' is the DialogChoice they clicked on.